# Mongoid: Retrieves all embedded documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Suppose we have these models:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :albums
end

class Album
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :photos
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

What I want is to retrieves all `Photo` of a particular `Person`. Is there a mongoid/mongodb shortcuts or the only way is to iterate over `person.albums` and store all `album.photos` in a new array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do this, one is through Mongoid, which, AFAIK, will inflate all objects.
Something like:

```
Person.only("albums.photos").where(id: '1').albums.map(&:photos).flatten
```

Or you can do it in Moped(driver) which will return only an array of photos.

```
Person.collection.find(id: "1").select("albums.photos" => 1).
first["albums"].map { |a| a["photos"] }.flatten
```

On the DB load, both dont make any difference, as they will yield the same query, only difference is that the first one will create way more objects than the second one.

Comment: In second case, the photos will be a `Photo` or an `Hash`?

Comment: Second case you will have only Hashes.